# How can I walk through embedded resources in a web page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-parsing

I'd like to be able to step through every embedded resource in a web page — CSS style sheets, external JavaScript files, images, iframes, etc. — and then do some stuff with them with JavaScript.

I can target them all separately, but I wonder if there isn't a more generic way.  Some built-in method or library that lets you walk through the DOM and interact with these kinds of embedded resources.

Is there?

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "walk through" and "interact".

Comment: Imaginary solution: fetch resources into an array that I can loop through.  Have the full URL of the resource in the array, and perhaps additional information available as well (what kind of resource it is, maybe, or whatever).  I can do all this on my own, coding a way to target every kind of resource I'm interested in, but I'm actually interested in all of this kind of resource, even if, say, something new is added in the future that I'm not aware of today.  So if there's a built-in, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [a lot of ways to gather DOM elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document#Methods), but the most common are the following:

```
document.body
document.getElementById()
document.getElementsByTagName()
document.getElementsByClassName()
document.querySelectorAll()
```

---

If you want to get all elements, without formal structure, you can do:

```
//non-standard
document.all

//or
document.getElementsByTagName('*');
```

Also, there is [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), which is the selector engine used by jQuery. It uses CSS selectors to target elements. Or if possible, use jQuery, which hosts a lot of DOM [traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) and [manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) methods.

Comment: Yes, but I was wondering if there was some sort of common attribute or method of access for embedded resources.

Comment: Looking for specific kinds of elements: ones that are hosted on another page and are embedded the current page.  CSS files, javascript, images, iframes, whatever else.  I was hoping there was some secret sauce that they all shared that could be used to select by.